# Broadcast receiver not invoked

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am having problems with my Broadcast not being received.

I have tried using a standard broadcast and a localbroadcast and neither will work.

This is the broadcast code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(WIFI_SKIPPED_INTENT);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

where WIFI_SKIPPED_INTENT = "com.wefi.wifi.skip"

And this is in my manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.wefi.receivers.WifiSkipReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.wefi.wifi.skip" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I added log commands before the sending and they are showing but logs in the receiver are not.

This happens on Android 11, Android 10 and Android 8 phones.

Edit:
If we register dynamically fro the receiver within the code then it works great. It fails only when registering through the manifest.

Comment: `WIFI_SKIPPED_INTENT` is not "com.wefi.wifi.skip"?

Comment: private static final String WIFI_SKIPPED_INTENT = "com.wefi.wifi.skip";